# How can I get shader performance statistics from the GPU?

Tags: performance, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, gpu

I am trying to understand the efficiency of my shaders on a number of pieces of hardware ( a PC and a number of Android devices ) and I would like a method for examining the GPU to understand how changes I make to my shader code affect the performance on the GPU.

What is the best technique for doing this ?

Comment: Qualcomm provides a profiler for their Adreno chips, and NVidia also has one for their Tegra platforms called PerfHUD ES. You can find both of them with a search engine. Then there's the [gltracer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/gltracer.html) for tracing GL ES commands.

Comment: The simplest way is to count FPS. I recommend to use an average FPS of last 100 rendered frames.

Comment: We use "PVRShaderEditor" for ios platform. Which gives the cycles taken by GPU to compile the shaders. And also act as a compilers. And i dn't know whether it's available for all platforms.